# Qwidget - Image Zoom in And Zoom Out Using Mouse Scroll

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

Currently, I use the class as below and promote it to graphics view to Zoom in and zoom out image. but how to stop zoom out when the resolution of image equals the original resolution of image and how to use press and hold scroll mouse to move picture when the resolution of image bigger than original resolution of image instead of use left mouse.

This is my code:

```
#include "custom_view.h"

Custom_View::Custom_View(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)
{

}

void Custom_View::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *_wheelEvent)
{
    setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
    setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);

    double scaleFactor = 1.2;
    if (_wheelEvent->delta()>0){
        scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
    }
    else
    {
        scale(1/scaleFactor,1/scaleFactor);
    }
}
```

My Question:
How to stop zoom out when the resolution of image equals the original resolution of image ? and how to use press and hold scroll mouse to move picture when the resolution of image bigger than original resolution of image instead of use left mouse.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: My Question is how to stop zoom out when the resolution of image equals the original resolution of image ? and how to use press and hold scroll mouse to move picture when the resolution of image bigger than original resolution of image instead of use left mouse. Thank you

Comment: if (this->transform().m11() < 1 || this->transform().m22() < 1) { scale(1 / this->transform().m11(), 1 / this->transform().m22()); }

Comment: @e.n.shirokov, Thank you so much, and do you know how to use press and hold scroll mouse to move picture when the resolution of image bigger than original resolution of image instead of use left mouse ?

Comment: I think you should override QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent() and catch Qt::MidButton event.